# Python project on TXT file, how to read-count words-lines and sorting

Tags: python

I have got a .txt file. I need to remove all characters that are not letters from the text, and then to print how many lines, characters is there in it. Then, I need to count how many times does every word appear in the file, and put this info into a dictionary. And then I need to print the top 3 frequent words and the top 1000 frequent words.

I have written this code, but it doesn't do the job. What is the problem?

```
def word_count(path):
    raws = 0
    file = open(path, 'r')
    while file.readline():
        raws += 1
    print ('There are', raws, 'raws in the TXT file')

    file = open(path, 'r')
    nchars = 0
    nwords = 0
    words = file.read().strip()
    words = words.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    for char in '#$%^&*-.:/()@\n1234567890;_':
        words = words.replace(char, ' ')
    words = words.lower()
    word_list = words.split()
    for word in word_list:
        nwords += 1
    for char in words:
        nchars += 1
    print ('There are', nwords, 'words in the TXT file')
    print ('There are', nchars, 'characters in the TXT file')


def word_frequency(path):
    dictionary = {}

    file = open(path, 'r')
    data = file.read()
    data = data.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    data = data.lower().split()

    for word in data:
        if not word[0] in '1234567890':
            if word in dictionary:
                dictionary[word] += 1
            else:
                dictionary[word] = 1


def most_appear_words(dictionary):
    new_d = collections._OrderedDictValuesView

     # new_d = sorted(dictionary)

    print 'The three most apppear word in the TXT file are:'
    for key in new_d:
        print (key, new_d[key])
```

Comment: Are you calling `word_count` at the end? Can you show us any output errors?

Comment: I'm having a problem with "word_frequency" function and "most_appear_words" function.
I cannot menage to put all of he words in a list and sorting the list so i can print the most 3 common words

Comment: _the code iv'e managed to write so far does not do the job, as well as the third function that do not works._ Can you be more specific? Please provide a [mcve]. As an aside, I would recommend using a context manager to handle file objects.

Comment: There are a few thing that can be redone, for example split() generates a list and getting the length of it is pretty easy (and you can also see what happens to a string). There is a built-in type called set, which is an unordered collection of unique elements. The string built-in type has a method called count that counts the ocurrence of a letter or a substring. The dictionary approach to store the frequency of each word is good. Now the only thing left (apart from refactorin the code because your files are open) is using sorted() to sort the dictionary by its values using list comprehension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, there are multiple problems with your code.
You are calling the builtin `open` three times. This means your code reads the whole file three times when one time should be enough. And whenever you are doing `file.read()` you are trying to read the whole file into memory. While this works fine for small files, a file that is too large to fit into memory will result in a `MemoryError`.

Your functions do way to much. They

- Open a file.
- They parse the file's content.
- They print the calculated statistics.

As a general advice, functions and objects should follow the [Single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

Currently your code does not work at all because in your function `most_appear_words` the brackets for the call to the  `print` function are missing. Also, you should never import any item with a name starting with an underscore like `collections._OrderedDictValuesView`. The underscore indicates that this view is for internal use only. You probably want to import `collections.Counter` here.

You do not provide a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So it is not clear how you are actually calling the functions in your code sample.

However, it looks like `word_frequency` is missing a `return` statement. In order to make your code work as it is, you would have to do something like

```py
def word_frequency(path):
    dictionary = {}

   # <insert your code here that updates dictionary>
   return dictionary    


def most_appear_words(dictionary):
    new_d = collections.Counter()
    # <insert your code here that updates and prints new_d>


if __name__ == '__main__':
   # <insert your code here>

   # feed the return of word_frequency to most_appear_words:
   d = word_frequency(your_path)
   most_appear_words(d)
```

I hope this will help you getting your code to work.

---

Please note, however, that I suggest a different approach:
Have one function responsible for opening and processing the file (`word_iterator`).
Have one function responsible for doing the statistics, i.e. counting words and letters (`word_count`).
Have one function to print the results to the console (`print_statistics`).

My suggested solution to the task would be:

```py
from collections import Counter
import string


def word_iterator(fp):
    t = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation + string.digits)

    word_no = 0
    with open(fp) as in_file:
        for line_no, line in enumerate(in_file, start=1):
            line = line.translate(t)
            words = line.split()
            for w in words:
                word_no += 1
                yield line_no, word_no, w.lower()


def word_count(word_iter):
    words = Counter()
    line_no = 0
    word_no = 0
    n_chars = 0

    for line_no, word_no, word in word_iter:
        n_chars += len(word)
        words.update([word])

    result = {
        'n_lines': line_no,
        'n_words': word_no,
        'n_chars': n_chars,
        'words': words
    }

    return result


def print_statistics(wc, top_n1=3, top_n2=None):
    print(' Word Count '.center(20, '='))
    print(f'File {fn} consists of')
    print(f' {wc["n_lines"]:5} lines')
    print(f' {wc["n_words"]:5} words')
    print(f' {wc["n_chars"]:5} characters')

    print()
    print(' Word Frequency '.center(20, '='))

    print(f'The {top_n1} most frequent words are:')
    for word, count in wc['words'].most_common(top_n1):
        print(f' {word} ({count} times)')

    if top_n2:
        print()
        print(f'The {top_n2} most frequent words are:')
        top_words = [w for w, _ in wc['words'].most_common(top_n2)]
        print(', '.join(top_words))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fn = 'text_file.txt'

    stat = word_count(word_iterator(fn))

    print_statistics(stat, top_n1=3, top_n2=1000)
```

With the sample output

```
==== Word Count ====
File text_file.txt consists of
     7 lines
   104 words
   492 characters

== Word Frequency ==
The 3 most frequent words are:
 a (5 times)
 the (4 times)
 it (3 times)

The 1000 most frequent words are:
a, the, it, content, of, lorem, ipsum, and, is, that, will, by, readable, page, using, as, here, like, many, web, their, sometimes, long, established, fact, reader, be, distracted, when, looking, at, its, layout, point, has, moreorless, normal, distribution, letters, opposed, to, making, look, english, desktop, publishing, packages, editors, now, use, default, model, text, search, for, uncover, sites, still, in, infancy, various, versions, have, evolved, over, years, accident, on, purpose, injected, humour
```